# Datepicker inside Bootstrap modal using Bootbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use a Datepicker inside a Bootbox modal but the problem is that the datepicker won't show the calendar inside the modal, but it works outside.

```
<button class="add_date_btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" taller_id="<?php htmlout($id); ?>">Add</button>
<div id="add_class_form" title="Agregar Clase">
    <form action="" method="post" id="form_clase">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Choose Date" id="datepicker" name="fecha" required />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

On the modal I'm loading the content of a hidden DIV using Bootbox:

```
$('.add_date_btn').on('click', function () {
      bootbox.dialog({
          message: $('#add_class_form').html(),
          title: "Add Class",
          buttons: {
              cancelar: {
                  label: "Cancelar",
                  className: "btn-default"
              }
          }
      });
  }); //End click
```

A sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4EjSW/

On my site the DIV #add_class_form is set to "display:none" but on the sample code I left it there so anyone can confirm it's actually working when it's outside the modal.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

```
 bootbox.dialog(
            {
                title: "Gestione Eventi",
                message: '<div class="row"> ' +
                         '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
                         '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
                         '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                         '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label> ' +
                         '<div class="col-md-4"> ' +
                         '<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-md datepicker"> ' +
                         '<span class="help-block">Here goes your name</span> </div> ' +
                         '</div> ' +
                         '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                         '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="awesomeness">How awesome is this?</label> ' +
                         '<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-0"> ' +
                         '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-0" value="Really awesome" checked="checked"> ' +
                         'Really awesome </label> ' +
                         '</div><div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-1"> ' +
                         '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-1" value="Super awesome"> Super awesome </label> ' +
                         '</div> ' +
                         '</div> </div>' +
                         '</form> </div> </div>',
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: "Save",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                            this.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

This works for me. After bootbox dialog call, into same scope, calling datepicker function..

Answer (score 0):

Try load message into bootbox in html version not raw string.

Replace it:

```
           message: $('#add_class_form').html(),
```

To:

```
           message: $('#add_class_form'),
```

See the results at: http://jsfiddle.net/ens1z/4EjSW/3/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was possible in JQuery. 
Your code works only the first time the Modal is opened. If I close the Modal and reopen it, the input field isn't there. Not sure why that's happening.